# Why is the list overwritten by the last item when using the same name for the loop variable?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, scope

I was trying to run this script in Python and I found something really strange:

```
test = ['file.txt', 'file1.mkv', 'file2.mkv']                                  
for test in test:
    print(test)    
print(test)
```

once I run this script I was expecting an output like this:

```
file.txt
file1.mkv
file2.mkv
['file.txt', 'file1.mkv', 'file2.mkv']
```

Instead what I get is this:

```
file.txt
file1.mkv
file2.mkv
file2.mkv
```

I can't understand why the last line of output is "file2.mkv".

In the script I said to print every value in `test` and then print `test`. I never wrote to change the variable `test` so there is no reason why the output is not the initial variable `test` that I defined at the beginning.

I know I am probably wrong, but I would like to understand why.

Comment: In the loop test is the local variable `test` (each element of the list `test`). After the loop, `test` is the top variable `test` (the list)

Comment: Try using `for t in test` to see if you can understand what is happening.

Comment: Maybe you can try to run here to see what is going on - pythontutor.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For loop overriding outer variables instead of creating new ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53356539/for-loop-overriding-outer-variables-instead-of-creating-new-ones)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
test = ['file.txt', 'file1.mkv', 'file2.mkv']                                  
for item in test:
    print(item)    
print(test)
```

Your last print was printing the last item in your loop which you called `test` as well as your list.

Answer (score 3):

Python does not have the same block logic as other languages. Variables declared inside a loop are still valid after the loop.

```
for i in range(5):
    pass
print(i)
```

will output `4`

whats actually happen is something like this:

```
# loop
i = 0
i = 1
i = 2
i = 3
i = 4
# end loop
print(i)  # print(4)
```

Because you named your loop variable the same as your array you are overriding the array variable with the individual values. That's the reason `test` contains `file2.mkv` after your loop.

[This questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611760/scoping-in-python-for-loops) provides some further details on this topic.